# Sigmoid using op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, diodes

I want to build a sigmoid function circuit using any of op-amps/diodes/resistors. The input will be one voltage \$x\$ into the sigmoid circuit. The output of the circuit should be: $$\frac1{1+e^{-x}}$$

The output range will be between 0 and 1 V. I looked online but could not find something that is doing this operation (or close) with the exponent. What would the circuit look like?

Comment: Uff, that's a hard one. I guess you come from a machine learning background and think this is a "native" function for anything? That's not the case. If you want an activation function, ReLu is easier – just a (half-wave) precision rectifier. A *symmetric* sigmoid will be nearly impossible, but if you're using an asymmetric for learning, you will get the most peculiar effects ;)

Comment: But *close* to a sigmoid would be what is called *soft clip/soft limiter* in audio, e.g. [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87989/how-do-i-implement-soft-clipping-in-an-audio-circuit-or-should-i-just-attenuate).

Comment: (most peculiar effects: the universal approximation theorem states that the activation function doesn't matter for the universality, as long as it's nonlinear. But if you're trying to adopt learned weights from a computer, where the sigmoid is perfect, to an analog ANN where it's asymmetric, your results will be biased)

Comment: I'd just check the literature and see what they use. There are many papers that describe circuits for analog neural nets.

Comment: Neural nets are not mentioned or tagged; is this application just a suspicion? Also not sure what relevance power electronics would be...

Comment: @TimWilliams 100% speculation on my side. But Sigmoid (and calling it Sigmoid) is very much something mostly encountered in neural networks. (excellent answer, btw, is that the Gilbert of the cell?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, the eponymous one :)

Comment: \$\frac1{1+e^{-x}}=\frac12+\frac12\tanh\frac{x}2\$. The \$\tanh\$ function is implemented by a differential long-tailed BJT pair but its \$\tanh\$ behavior exists over only a very small \$\pm\$ differential voltage input range. The \$\frac{x}2\$ part will need to be brought into its range, first. Barrie's MC1496 comes to mind, though it may be tricky to operate for this purpose. (Must be more modern related parts around, today.) Pretty much any of the professional engineers here can get it done. You may need to write about input sources and output loads.

Comment: User32xxx, [here's a highly simplified behavioral example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8W6l.png). But you will have to write more, I think.

Comment: @TimWilliams removed the [tag:power-electronics]. Really wishing OP would say a word or two on their applications, but they seem to have taken a dive...

Comment: Does it have to be op amps? This is a very difficult function to do with op amps. It's a very difficult function to do with analog electronics in general.

Comment: If what you're looking for is only some generic smooth limiting function then you may be able to work with two antiparallel diodes, or maybe 2 in series on each leg and a high resistance (tens of k\$\Omega\$). It won't gove you all the smoothness but, it will limit the signal. For additional limiting you can use an opamp, or a discrete differential transistor stage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, neural net for updating weights

Answer (score 6):

Op-amps won't help very much directly, but consider finding a solution as a truncated series of tanh(x) functions, which use the transfer function of the BJT diff pair.  A variety of trig functions can be derived this way; see e.g. the classic [US4475169A High-accuracy sine-function generator](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4475169A/en) by Barrie Gilbert.  Op-amps will assist for setting bias, setting and receiving voltages and currents (especially differentially), etc.

If not, the direct analog computer implementation is to prepare the steps as given.  So, an exponential converter of the inverse of the input (e<sup>-x</sup>), then a multiplier (using op-amps and diodes: two more exponentiators, an adder, and a logger), then a feedback loop to invert the multiplier into a divider.  (The "1+" is trivial as an offset.)  Big PITA and tons of error, especially temperature sensitivity with a discrete implementation.  I mean, that's true of analog functions anyway, but the Gilbert approach is likely the closest fitting and least error prone method for this particular function.

Comment: One trick, you can reformulate \$\frac1{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}\$, so you can at least use a transistor (or diode if you can condition the input current) directly for the non-inverted exponential. But the real kicker is probably the division, right?

Comment: (other than that, if you can "easily" do a \$e^{-\alpha x}\,\alpha >0\$, then you could do \$e^{-\alpha_1 (1+e^{-\alpha_2 x})}\$ and get the generalized form of OP's sigmoid.)

Comment: Very nice answer, Tim, as \$\frac1{1+e^{-x}}=\frac12+\frac12\tanh\frac{x}2\$. It's how I'd approach it, too. And you are bringing back memories again of being at Barrie's funeral reception more than 2 years ago somewhere in between Beaverton and Aloha, Oregon.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks. I am not familiar with electronics and circuits. How do I do the exp operation? Thanks.

Comment: see Tim's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what accuracy you need but I have a simplification for you.

$$
y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \\
$$

This function is quite linear in range {-0.7, +0.7}. And loses linearity for \$x\$ values above 0.7, and finally sits asymptotically to 1 for \$x\$ values above 4.

Approximating the function for \$x \leq 1\$ will introduce a slight error. Using a \$(x, y)\$ data pair array for \$x\$ range of {0, 1} I simplified the function as

$$
y\approx 0.25\ x+0.5
$$

This should be easy to implement with op amps. The most difficult part is generating an accurate 0.5V offset because it affects the accuracy directly.

Please note that this is an approximation and therefore produces slight deviation, especially for \$x\$ values above 0.2. Here are some error data for different \$x\$ values:

- **x = 0.2:** The actual result is 0.54983, simplification produces 0.55. The error is 0.03%.
- **x = 0.3:** The actual result is 0.57444, simplification produces 0.575. The error is almost zero.
- **x = 0.5:** The actual result is 0.62246, simplification produces 0.625. The error is 0.5%.
- **x = 0.6:** The actual result is 0.64565, simplification produces 0.65. The error is around +0.67%.
- **x = 0.7:** The actual result is 0.66879, simplification produces 0.675. The error is around +0.9%.
- **x = 0.8:** The actual result is 0.68997, simplification produces 0.69. The error is almost zero.
- **x = 1.0:** The actual result is 0.73106, simplification produces 0.75. The error is 2.6% (max error).

Comment: how do you get y≈0.25 x+0.5 from the prev eqn?

Comment: @user324288 as I said in my answer the original function is quite linear for x values between -0.7 and +0.7. Since your x values will change between 0 and 1, the function can be approximated to a linear one. So I prepared a table of different x-y values for the original function. Then I tried to find a "fashion" of changing by trial-error with x-y values. Originally I ended up with \$y \approx x+0.5 (1−1.5 x)\$ which can be re-arranged to \$y\approx 0.25 x+0.5\$. Please note that the original function loses linearity above 0.7, so the linear approximation hits its max error at x = 1.